# Python, Numpy. Как преобразовать чёрно-белую картинку в массив Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Как преобразовать чёрно-белую картинку 28x28 в (float или int) массив Numpy

Comment: Можно использовать Pillow и далее попиксельно с шагом создать массив

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: img_arr = numpy.array(Image.open('my_img.png')

Answer (score 2):

Видел такой способ

```
 from PIL import Image
 import numpy

 im = Image.open('с:/test.png')
 im  = im.convert('L') # делаем черно-белым
 pixels = numpy.asarray(im)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('C:/image.png', 0) # 0 - этот параметр вернёт ч\б изображение
print(type(image))  # type(image) == numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: Использовать модуль компьютерного зрения просто для загрузки картинки - немного оверкилл.